# Change color of svg on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two svg items, one for a + sign and one for a minus sign. I want to turn them both white on hover, but it doesn't work, here is the html:

```css
zoom-control svg g path:hover {
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <zoom-control class="first-btn" :isFirst="true" :handler="attachZoomInHandler">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#00A6CE" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M18 12H6M12 18V6"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </zoom-control>
  <zoom-control class="last-btn" :isLast="true" :handler="attachZoomOutHandler">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#00A6CE" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" d="M18 12H6"/>
    </svg>
  </zoom-control>
</div>
```

Why is it not working and how can I turn them white on hover?

Comment: Try `fill: white;` instead of `color: white`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the css selection a bit for it to work:

```css
zoom-control svg:hover path {
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <zoom-control class="first-btn" :isFirst="true" :handler="attachZoomInHandler">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#00A6CE" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M18 12H6M12 18V6"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </zoom-control>
  <zoom-control class="last-btn" :isLast="true" :handler="attachZoomOutHandler">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#00A6CE" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" d="M18 12H6"/>
    </svg>
  </zoom-control>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, you could also do `zoom-control svg path:hover` if you want the change of color to only happen when you're hovering directly over the shape not the bounding box.